# Chrome on iPad, Picture-in-Picture and Screen Time not working

Tags: ipad, google-chrome, screen-time

I have time limits defined for an iPad via the Screen Time settings. This works well, even for Chrome in general. However, the Picture-in-Picture (PiP) feature of Chrome does not get blocked by Screen Time for some reason. So my children have discovered that when their time limit runs out on the device, they can use the "One More Minute" feature of Screen Time to unlock Chrome, go to YouTube (or similar), and turn on the Picture-In-Picture mode of Chrome so they can continue to watch videos.

(They actually use the Picture-in-Picture mode for multitasking in their normal viewing workflow, so I don't want to delete Chrome nor inhibit PiP mode entirely.)

How can I make the PiP mode of Chrome respect the Screen Time limits?